# HTML: how to create <a> below another <a>?

Tags: html, css

On my page there's a `<div>` which is a link to `address1`. The corner of that Div there's a drop-down menu with a link to `address2`. From some reason, the second link cancels the first one, and so Link1 cannot be clicked.

[image: example]

In the attached image - the Link1 text, the image and the blue section should all link to `address1`, and only Link2, which appear when I hover over the arrow, should point to `address2`. Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head><body><center>
    <a href="address1">
    <div class="card">
<div class="dropdown"><img src="img/dropdown.png" class="dropdownarrow"><div class="dropdown-content">
<a class="dropdown-content-item" href="address2">Link2</a>
</div></div><img src="img/smiley.png" class="cardimg">
      <div class="container" align="center">
        Link1
      </div>
    </div></a>
</center></body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: #d3f3ff
}

.cardimg { 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px; 
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownarrow  {
  background-color: #96ffcc;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant place an `a` inside of an `a` in [html markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (have a look at Permitted parents).

```css
.card {
  /* padding-top: 20px; */
  /* REMOVED*/
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #d3f3ff
}

.cardimg {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.cardbg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownarrow {
  background-color: #96ffcc;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-item {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


/* ADDED */

.card-link {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="dropdown"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30" class="dropdownarrow">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="dropdown-content-item" href="address2">Link2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- moved a below absolute container -->
    <a class="card-link" href="address1">
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/300/100" class="cardimg">
      <div class="container" align="center">
        Link1
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a workaround that works: I added a blank image in the background of the `div`, and changed the location of the `<a>` tag. I used plenty of `position` in the CSS and a `z-index` to make sure the menu is on top, but it all works just fine eventually. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="dropdown"><img src="img/dropdown.png" class="dropdownarrow"><div class="dropdown-content">
<a class="dropdown-content-item" href="address2">Link2</a>
</div></div>
      <a href="address1"><img src="img/blank.png" class="cardbg"><img src="img/smiley.png" class="cardimg">
      <div class="container" align="center">
        Link1 
      </div></a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: #d3f3ff
}

.cardimg { 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.cardbg {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px; 
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownarrow  {
  background-color: #96ffcc;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```css
.card {
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: #d3f3ff
}

.cardimg { 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px; 
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownarrow  {
  background-color: #96ffcc;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head><body><center>
    
    <div class="card">
<div class="dropdown"><img src="img/dropdown.png" class="dropdownarrow"><div class="dropdown-content">
<a class="dropdown-content-item" href="address2">Link2</a>
</div></div><img src="img/smiley.png" class="cardimg">
      <div class="container" align="center">
       <a href="address1"> Link1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</center></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will make the image and the blue part not be a part of the link, and they should be. I want to be able to click anywhere in `card` (not me downvoting..)

Comment: ah shit it looked like the link 1 should be the gray "button" at the bottom

Answer (score -1):

if your image is correct, and the link 1 should be the gray bottom, then this works:

```css
.card {
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: #d3f3ff
}

.cardimg { 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px; 
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownarrow  {
  background-color: #96ffcc;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
}

.card a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
      <div class="dropdown">
      <img src="img/dropdown.png" class="dropdownarrow"><div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="dropdown-content-item" href="address2">Link2</a>
      </div>
    </div><img src="img/smiley.png" class="cardimg">
    <a href="address1">
      <div class="container" align="center">
        Link1
      </div>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: who downvoted me and why? this works as he wants it to be ^^

Comment: Thanks, but this will make the image and the blue part not be a part of the link, and they should be. I want to be able to click anywhere in `card` (not me downvoting..)